# What is the inverse Laplace of a complete square?

Tags: laplace-transform

How do I find the inverse Laplace for something like this ?

$${8 \over  ( s^2 + 16 )^2    }$$

I tried using partial fraction but it didn't help
any ideas on how to do it using differentiation or convolution theorem? or any other way !

Comment: Why did partial fractions not help?

Comment: because i still have the (s^2+16)^2 in the denominator of the decomposed expression !?  
is there any other way to do it? using differentiation for example!?

Comment: $(s^2+16) = (s+4i)(s-4i)$.

Answer (score 1):

By the residue theorem, the inverse Laplace transform of the above expression is

$$\left [\frac{d}{ds} \frac{8\,e^{s t}}{(s+4 i)^2} \right ]_{s=4 i} + \left [\frac{d}{ds} \frac{8\,e^{s t}}{(s-4 i)^2} \right ]_{s=-4 i}$$

Comment: Can you expand on how you use the residue theorem to compute the inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: The ILT may be shown to be equal to the sum of the residues of the poles of the LT times $e^{s t}$ for $t \gt 0$.  As we have double poles, the residues are first derivatives of the integrand without the double pole.